# ActionScript 3, Check if font style is available

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, fonts, flex4.5

Does as3 have any way to determine if a font can support certain styles, e.g. bold & italic.

Something like .NET's isStyleAvailable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FontDescription.isFontCompatible` to find out if a font supports certain styles or not. Just run the function for bold, normal and italic and you should have what you need.

Comment: That's the one I was looking for :)